# Построение оптимального сплайна Безье (C#). Проблема с нахождением контрольных точек

Tags: c#, алгоритм, интерполяция

Реализую свой метод интерполяции сплайна Безье дефекта 1. Перед написанием кода вдохновлялся этим [Построение оптимального сплайна Безье](http://mech.math.msu.su/~fpm/ps/k16/k163/k16304.pdf). Реализовал метод с стандартной параметризацией (не учитывающий расстояние между узлами интерполяции), вышло г#&но, почему не ясно. При подстановке координат из данного примера результаты аналогичные тому, что получилось у них (а тобишь все верно). Подскажите ошибку! Проблема в методе StandartParameter, других причин не вижу.

П.С. Если кто будет читать про сплайны из ссылки, имейте в виду что второй пример посчитан не верно. Ошибка в том, что при расчетах они в формуле 16 взяли α2i−1Qi1 вместо α2i−1Qi−1.

При реализации данной задачи возникла необходимость решать СЛАУ. Выложу заодно и его реализацию (Matrix).

[image: Результат работы программы]

```
                          Результат работы программы.
```

А вот собственно код метода интерполяции:

```
/// <summary>
/// Предоставляет методы для интерполяции сплайнов.
/// </summary>
public static class SplineInterpolation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Возвращает массив координат <see cref="Point"/> заданного сплайна.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="interpolationNodes"> Массив <see cref="Point"/> содержащий узлы интерполяции.</param>
    public static Point[] SplineBezierOptimal(Point[] interpolationNodes)
    {           
        return SplineBezier(interpolationNodes, StandartParameter(interpolationNodes));
    }


    // Расчет координат сплайна
    private static Point[] SplineBezier(Point[] interpolationNodes, Matrix controlPoint)
    {
        Point[] point = new Point[0]; //Массив содержит рассчитываемые координаты

        // Итератор кривых
        for (int numberCurve = 0; numberCurve < interpolationNodes.GetLength(0) - 1; numberCurve++)
        {


            // Рассчт координат либо по Х либо по Y
            if (Math.Abs(interpolationNodes[numberCurve + 1].X - interpolationNodes[numberCurve].X) >= Math.Abs(interpolationNodes[numberCurve + 1].Y - interpolationNodes[numberCurve].Y))
            {
                int startPosicion = point.GetLength(0); // Начальный индекс расширенной части массива 

                // Увеличивается на число, равное полному количеству точек кривой - 1, т.к. последняя точка не включается
                Array.Resize<Point>(ref point, point.GetLength(0) + Math.Abs(interpolationNodes[numberCurve + 1].X - interpolationNodes[numberCurve].X));

                // Задаем начальную координату Y
                point[startPosicion].Y = interpolationNodes[numberCurve].Y;

                // t - линейный параметр кубической функции Безье, dt  - прирощение.
                // dt расчитанно таким образом, что позволяет расчитать значения для каждой координаты наибольшей орты
                double dt = (double)1 / Math.Abs(interpolationNodes[numberCurve + 1].X - interpolationNodes[numberCurve].X);
                double t = dt; // Не ноль, по тому, что "первая итерация" пропущенна, т.к. координаты начала заданы 

                // Уравнение кубичиской кривой Безье
                for (int i = 1; i + startPosicion < point.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    point[startPosicion + i].Y = (int)Math.Round(Math.Pow((1 - t), 3) * interpolationNodes[numberCurve].Y +
                                                                 Math.Pow((1 - t), 2) * (double)(controlPoint[numberCurve, 1]) * 3 * t +
                                                                 Math.Pow(t, 2) * (double)(controlPoint[numberCurve + 1, 1]) * 3 * (1 - t) +
                                                                 Math.Pow(t, 3) * interpolationNodes[numberCurve + 1].Y);
                    t += dt;
                }
                 // Линейно дополняем Х
                for (int i = 0; i + startPosicion < point.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    point[startPosicion + i].X = (Math.Sign(interpolationNodes[numberCurve + 1].X - interpolationNodes[numberCurve].X) * i) +
                                                 interpolationNodes[numberCurve].X;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                int startPosicion = point.GetLength(0);

                Array.Resize<Point>(ref point, point.GetLength(0) + Math.Abs(interpolationNodes[numberCurve + 1].Y - interpolationNodes[numberCurve].Y));

                point[startPosicion].X = interpolationNodes[numberCurve].X;

                double dt = (double)1 / Math.Abs(interpolationNodes[numberCurve + 1].Y - interpolationNodes[numberCurve].Y);
                double t = dt;

                for (int i = 1; i + startPosicion < point.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    point[startPosicion + i].X = (int)Math.Round( Math.Pow((1 - t), 3) * interpolationNodes[numberCurve].X +
                                                                  Math.Pow((1 - t), 2) * (double)(controlPoint[numberCurve, 0]) * 3 * t +
                                                                  Math.Pow(t, 2) * (double)(controlPoint[numberCurve + 1, 0]) * 3 * (1 - t) +
                                                                  Math.Pow(t, 3) * interpolationNodes[numberCurve + 1].X);
                    t += dt;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i + startPosicion < point.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    point[startPosicion + i].Y = (Math.Sign(interpolationNodes[numberCurve + 1].Y - interpolationNodes[numberCurve].Y) * i) +
                                                 interpolationNodes[numberCurve].Y;
                }
            }
        }

        // Добовляем элемент вмассив и заносим в него координаты последней точки сплайна
        Array.Resize<Point>(ref point, point.GetLength(0) + 1);

        point[point.GetLength(0) - 1].X = interpolationNodes[interpolationNodes.GetLength(0) - 1].X;
        point[point.GetLength(0) - 1].Y = interpolationNodes[interpolationNodes.GetLength(0) - 1].Y;

        return point;
    }


    // Расчет контрольных точек
    private static Matrix StandartParameter(Point[] interpolationNodes)
    {
        // Основная матрица системы mainMatrix имеет размерность 2n x 2n, где 2n - количество контрольных точек. 
        // Поскольку на одну кривую приходится 2n контрольных точек, а количество кривых B равняется количество узлов интерполяции Q - 1.
        // Следовательно количество контрольных точек 2(Q - 1).
        int controlPointRange = 2 * (interpolationNodes.GetLength(0) - 1);

        Matrix mainMatrix = new Matrix(controlPointRange, controlPointRange);

        // Матрица свободных челенов freeMatrix.
        Matrix freeMatrix_X = new Matrix(controlPointRange, 1);
        Matrix freeMatrix_Y = new Matrix(controlPointRange, 1);

        // Первая строка mainMatrix согласно формулам 2A0 − B0 = Q0 имеет формат [2, -1, 0, 0 ... 0], а последняя согласно 2Bn−1 − An−1 = Qn [0 ... 0, 0, -1, 2].
        // Согласно этим формулам значения первой и последней строки freeMatrix будет [0, 0] и [interpolationNodes[maxIndex].X, interpolationNodes[maxIndex].Y] соответственно.
        mainMatrix[0, 0] = 2;
        mainMatrix[0, 1] = -1;
        mainMatrix[controlPointRange - 1, controlPointRange - 1] = 2;
        mainMatrix[controlPointRange - 1, controlPointRange - 2] = -1;
        freeMatrix_X[controlPointRange - 1, 0] = interpolationNodes[interpolationNodes.GetLength(0) - 1].X;
        freeMatrix_Y[controlPointRange - 1, 0] = interpolationNodes[interpolationNodes.GetLength(0) - 1].Y;

        // Остальные строки матрицы mainMatrix рекурсивно заполняются значениями 1, -2, 2, -1 и 0, 1, 1, 0 со смещением на [i + 2, j + 2] 
        // каждую иттерацию. Примечание: согласно формулам Ai−1 − 2Bi−1 + 2Ai − Bi = 0 и Bi−1 + Ai = 2Qi соответственно.
        // Массив freeMatrix будт заполняться значениями соответствующими interpolationNodes[maxIndex] умноженными на 2.
        // Индексация начинается с 2 строки и до предпоследней т.к. они уже заполнены.
        for (int i = 1, inpIndex = 1; i < controlPointRange - 2; i += 2, inpIndex++)
        {
            mainMatrix[i, i - 1] = 1;
            mainMatrix[i, i + 0] = -2;
            mainMatrix[i, i + 1] = 2;
            mainMatrix[i, i + 2] = -1;
            mainMatrix[i + 1, i + 0] = 1;
            mainMatrix[i + 1, i + 1] = 1;

            freeMatrix_X[i + 1, 0] = 2 * interpolationNodes[inpIndex].X;
            freeMatrix_Y[i + 1, 0] = 2 * interpolationNodes[inpIndex].Y;
        }

        // Решение систем относительно Х и Y(нахождение Х и Y координат контрольных точек соответственно)
        freeMatrix_X = Matrix.SLAE(mainMatrix, freeMatrix_X);
        freeMatrix_Y = Matrix.SLAE(mainMatrix, freeMatrix_Y);

        // Упаковка значений из freeMatrix_X и freeMatrix_Y в структуру Point
        Matrix point = new Matrix(controlPointRange, 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < controlPointRange; i++)
        {
            point[i, 0] = freeMatrix_X[i, 0];
            point[i, 1] = freeMatrix_Y[i, 0];
        }

        return point;           
    }

}
```

А вот расчет СЛАУ:

```
 /// <summary>
/// Предоставляет методы для работы с матрицами и решения СЛАУ матричным способом.
/// </summary>
public class Matrix
{
    private decimal[,] _array;


    // Индексатор
    public decimal this[int i, int j]
    {
        get
        {
            return _array[i, j];
        }

        set
        {
            if ((i > _array.GetLength(0) - 1) || (j > _array.GetLength(1) - 1))
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Индекс находится вне границ матрицы.");
            }

            _array[i, j] = Convert.ToDecimal(value);
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Инициализирует новый экземпляр класса <see cref="Matrix"/> размерности [1, 1].
    /// </summary>
    public Matrix()
    {
        _array = new decimal[1, 1];
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Инициализирует новый экземпляр класса <see cref="Matrix"/> размерности [i, j].
    /// </summary>
    public Matrix(int i, int j)
    {
        if ((i == 0) || (j == 0))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Одно из измерений переданного в метод массива равняется 0.");
        }

        _array = new decimal[i, j];
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Инициализирует новый экземпляр класса <see cref="Matrix"/> равного по размеру и содержанию переданному массиву.
    /// </summary>
    public Matrix(decimal[,] array)
    {
        if ((array.GetLength(0) == 0) || (array.GetLength(1) == 0))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("По крайней мере одно из измерений переданного в метод массива равняется 0.");
        }

        _array = new decimal[array.GetLength(0), array.GetLength(1)];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                    _array[i, j] = array[i, j];
            }
        }                                
    }


    // Оператор "*".
    public static Matrix operator *(Matrix matrix, decimal factor)
    {
        Matrix temp = new Matrix(matrix.GetLength(0), matrix.GetLength(1));

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                temp[i, j] = matrix[i, j] * factor;
            }
        }

        return temp;
    }


    // Оператор "*".
    public static Matrix operator *(Matrix matrix_1, Matrix matrix_2)
    {
        if (matrix_1.GetLength(1) != matrix_2.GetLength(0)) // Если количество столбцов matrix_1 не равно количеству строк matrix_2, умножение не возможно
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Rоличество столбцов matrix_1 не равно количеству строк matrix_2.");
        }

        Matrix temp = new Matrix(matrix_1.GetLength(0), matrix_2.GetLength(1));

        // Первые два цикла переберают все элементы массива
        for (int target_i = 0; target_i < temp.GetLength(0); target_i++)    // target_i - строка текущего элемента
        {
            for (int target_j = 0; target_j < temp.GetLength(1); target_j++)    // target_j - колонка текущего элемента
            {
                // Третий цикл суммирует произведения соответствющих элементов target_i строки matrix_1 и target_j колонки matrix_2
                decimal result = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < temp.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    result += matrix_1[target_i, i] * matrix_2[i, target_j];
                    //result += matrix_1[i, target_j] * matrix_2[target_i, i];
                }

                temp[target_i, target_j] = result;
            }
        }

        return temp;

    }


    // Оператор "+".
    public static Matrix operator +(Matrix matrix_1, Matrix matrix_2)
    {
        if ((matrix_1.GetLength(0) != matrix_2.GetLength(0)) || (matrix_1.GetLength(1) != matrix_2.GetLength(1)))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Сложение матриц разной размерности.");
        }

        Matrix temp = new Matrix(matrix_1.GetLength(0), matrix_1.GetLength(1));

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix_1.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix_1.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                temp[i, j] = matrix_1[i, j] + matrix_2[i, j];
            }
        }

        return temp;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Решение системы линейных алгебраических уравнений.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="A">Основная матрица системы.</param>
    /// <param name="B">Матрица свободных членов.</param>
    public static Matrix SLAE(Matrix A, Matrix B)
    {
        return A.Invert() * B;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Возвращает обратную матрицу <see cref="Matrix"/>. 
    /// </summary>
    public Matrix Invert()
    {
        Matrix copy = new Matrix(_array);

        copy = copy.AlgebraicComplementMatrix();
        copy.Transpose();
        copy = copy * (1 / (new Matrix(_array).Determinant()));

        return copy;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Получает определитель матрицы <see cref="Matrix"/>.
    /// </summary>       
    public decimal Determinant()
    {
        // Определитель находится методом Гаусса

        if (_array.GetLength(0) != _array.GetLength(1))
        {
            throw new MemberAccessException("Невозможно вычислить определитель матрицы если она имеет не квадратный вид.");
        }

        // Определитель матрицы первого порядка есть сама матрица

        if (_array.GetLength(0) == 1)
        {
            return _array[0, 0];
        }

        decimal[,] temp = new decimal[_array.GetLength(0), _array.GetLength(1)];
        Array.Copy(_array, temp, _array.GetLength(0) * _array.GetLength(1));  // Локальная копия массива создается для того, что бы не изменять переданный массив

        int s = 1; // Коэффициент оприделяющий знак определителя

        // Приведение матрицы к треугольному виду 
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.GetLength(0) - 1; i++)    // (n - i) - порядок обрабатываемой матрицы
        {
            for (int j = i; j < temp.GetLength(0) - 1; j++)    // j - строки обрабатываемой матрицы
            {
                // Исключение нулей в главной диагонали
                if (temp[i, i] == 0)
                {
                    int d = 1;

                    while (true)    // Поиск ненулевого элемента ряда (i + d)
                    {
                        if (d + i > temp.GetLength(0) - 1)    // Если поиск вышел за границы массива, то ряд нулевой => вернуть 0 
                        {
                            return 0;
                        }

                        if (temp[i, i + d] != 0)
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                        d++;
                    }

                    // Обмен местами колонки m и n в массиве temp

                    decimal tempSwap;

                    for (int k = 0; k < temp.GetLength(0); k++)
                    {
                        tempSwap = temp[k, i + d];
                        temp[k, i + d] = temp[k, i];
                        temp[k, i] = tempSwap;
                    }

                    s = s * -1;
                }

                // Приведение j + 1 строки к виду [0, Х, Х ... Х]
                if (temp[j + 1, i] == 0)  // если следующий элемент столбца и так 0, то приведение не требуются
                {
                    continue;
                }

                decimal divider = temp[j + 1, i] / temp[i, i];

                for (int k = i; k < temp.GetLength(0); k++)   // k - элементы обрабатываемой строки
                {
                    temp[j + 1, k] = temp[j + 1, k] - (temp[i, k] * divider);
                }
            }
        }

        // Вычисление произведения главной диагонали
        decimal determinant = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            determinant = (temp[i, i] * determinant);
        }

        return s * determinant;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Получает минор элемента [i, j] матрицы <see cref="Matrix"/>. 
    /// </summary>
    public decimal GetMinor(int i, int j)
    {
        if ((i > _array.GetLength(0) - 1) || (j > _array.GetLength(1) - 1))
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Индекс находился вне границ матрицы.");
        }

        if (_array.GetLength(0) != _array.GetLength(1))
        {
            throw new MemberAccessException("Невозможно вычислить минор матрицы если она имеет не квадратный вид.");
        }

        if (_array.GetLength(0) == 1)
        {
            throw new MemberAccessException("Невозможно вычислить минор матрицы первого порядка.");
        }

        decimal[,] temp = new decimal[_array.GetLength(0) - 1, _array.GetLength(1) - 1];

        // Циклы переберают все элементы массива за исключением элемента соответствующего позиции (target_i, target_j)
        for (int k = 0, matrixTemp_i = 0; k < _array.GetLength(0); k++)
        {
            if (k == i)
            {
                continue;
            }

            for (int l = 0, matrixTemp_j = 0; l < _array.GetLength(1); l++)
            {
                if (l == j)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                temp[matrixTemp_i, matrixTemp_j] = _array[k, l];

                matrixTemp_j++;
            }

            matrixTemp_i++;
        }

        return new Matrix(temp).Determinant();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Получает алгебраическое дополнение элемента [i, j], матрицы <see cref="Matrix"/>. 
    /// </summary>
    public decimal AlgebraicComplement(int i, int j)
    {
        if ((i > _array.GetLength(0) - 1) || (j > _array.GetLength(1) - 1))
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Индекс находился вне границ матрицы.");
        }

        return (new Matrix(_array).GetMinor(i, j)) * Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Pow(-1, ((i + 1) + (j + 1))));           
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Получает матрицу алгебраических дополнений матрицы <see cref="Matrix"/>. 
    /// </summary>
    public Matrix AlgebraicComplementMatrix()
    {


        Matrix temp = new Matrix(_array.GetLength(0), _array.GetLength(1));
        Matrix copy = new Matrix(_array);

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < temp.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                temp[i, j] = copy.AlgebraicComplement(i, j);
            }
        }

        return temp;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Транспонирование матрицы <see cref="Matrix"/>. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="matrix">Двумерный массив, представляющий собой матрицу <see cref="Matrix"/>.</param>
    public void Transpose()
    {
        decimal[,] temp = new decimal[_array.GetLength(1), _array.GetLength(0)];

        for (int i = 0; i < _array.GetLength(0); i++)    // i - строки обрабатываемой матрицы
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < _array.GetLength(1); j++)    // j - элементы строки обрабатываемой матрицы
            {
                temp[j, i] = _array[i, j];
            }
        }

        _array = temp;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Получает 32-разрядное число, представляющее количество элементов в заданном измерении матрицы <see cref="Matrix"/>. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dimension">Измерение матрицы <see cref="Matrix"/>, индексация которой начинается с нуля, и для которого необходимо определить длинну.</param>
    public int GetLength(int dimension)
    {
        if (dimension == 0)
        {
            return _array.GetLength(0);
        }
        else if (dimension == 1)
        {
            return _array.GetLength(1);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Не существующее измерение матрицы.");
        }           
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Получает массив <see cref="decimal"/> из матрицы <see cref="Matrix"/>. 
    /// </summary>
    public decimal[,] GetArray(Matrix matrix)
    {
        return _array;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Меняет местами строки m и n в массиве <see cref="Matrix"/>. 
    /// </summary>
    public void SwapArrayRow(int m, int n)
    {
        if ((m > _array.GetLength(0) - 1) || (n > _array.GetLength(0) - 1))
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Индекс находился вне границ матрицы.");
        }

        if (m > _array.GetLength(1) - 1 || n > _array.GetLength(1) - 1)
        {
            return;
        }

        decimal temp;

        for (int i = 0; i < _array.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            temp = _array[n, i];
            _array[n, i] = _array[m, i];
            _array[m, i] = temp;
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Меняет местами колонки m и n в массиве <see cref="Matrix"/>. 
    /// </summary>
    private void SwapArrayColumn(int m, int n)
    {
        if ((m > _array.GetLength(1) - 1) || (n > _array.GetLength(1) - 1))
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Индекс находился вне границ матрицы.");
        }

        if (m > _array.GetLength(0) - 1 || n > _array.GetLength(0) - 1)
        {
            return;
        }

        decimal temp;

        for (int i = 0; i < _array.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            temp = _array[i, n];
            _array[i, n] = _array[i, m];
            _array[i, m] = temp;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем и целом ларчик просто открывался... В методе SplineBezier необходимо заменить

```
// Уравнение кубичиской кривой Безье
            for (int i = 1; i + startPosicion < point.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                point[startPosicion + i].Y = (int)Math.Round(Math.Pow((1 - t), 3) * interpolationNodes[numberCurve].Y +
                                                             Math.Pow((1 - t), 2) * (double)(controlPoint[numberCurve, 1]) * 3 * t +
                                                             Math.Pow(t, 2) * (double)(controlPoint[numberCurve + 1, 1]) * 3 * (1 - t) +
                                                             Math.Pow(t, 3) * interpolationNodes[numberCurve + 1].Y);
                t += dt;
            }
```

На

```
// Уравнение кубичиской кривой Безье
                for (int i = 1; i + startPosicion < point.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    point[startPosicion + i].Y = (int)Math.Round(Math.Pow((1 - t), 3) * interpolationNodes[numberCurve].Y +
                                                                 Math.Pow((1 - t), 2) * (double)(controlPoint[2 * numberCurve, 1]) * 3 * t +
                                                                 Math.Pow(t, 2) * (double)(controlPoint[2 * numberCurve + 1, 1]) * 3 * (1 - t) +
                                                                 Math.Pow(t, 3) * interpolationNodes[numberCurve + 1].Y);
                    t += dt;
                }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
                                      Для сравнения.

Comment: Все равно сплайн кривой, особенно первый сегмент. Ошибку искать в этой простыне никто не станет, но результаты должны получиться [такие](https://ideone.com/EXvnkD). и [такие](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qv6hc3celelkvn8/spline.png?dl=0)